# Php script generates div containers. I need margin-left on the second one created

Tags: php, html, css

this might be a dumb question but I am really new to all the PHP stuff etc so I will just ask here.

I made this script here where it generates as many div containers with my Database values inside of sertant texts as long as there are values left in the database to make. How can I get the second div that gets created to have a margin-left ?

```
  <?php
    // Connect to the database
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    // Retrieve data from the "whois" table
    $sql = "SELECT Headline, Content, Link, BtnText FROM whois";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // Insert the data into the HTML code
            echo '
                      <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <div class="box-item">
                                <div class="tittle-text">
                                    <h3 class="mb-0 font-d-bld">' . $row["Headline"] . '</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="content-text">
                                    <ul class="mb-0 ps-0">
                                        <li>
                                            <p class="mb-0 font-d-bld text-white">' . $row["Content"] . '</p>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="play-btn">
                                    <a target="blank" href="' . $row["Link"] . '" class="text-uppercase text-white font-d-bld">' . $row["BtnText"] . '</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ';
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    
    // Close the database connection
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the resulting HTML that this produces, and can you [target your element with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)?

Comment: 'Remember' on what row you are, then you can use an `if` to add some styling or even better, a CSS class that will apply the margin.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to can achieve this but based on your provided code here is one way to do it ...

**css**

```
    <style>
        .leftmargin {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
```

**php**:

```
//set the counter
 $counter = 1;
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               //check if its second iteration 
                if($counter == 2) {
                    $MarginClass = ".marginleft"; // or any class if bootstrap ml-2 or so on
                }else{
                    $MarginClass = "";
                }


            // Insert the data into the HTML code
                //add margin class on 2nd row....
            echo '

                      <div class="col-lg-5 '.$MarginClass.'">
                            <div class="box-item">
                                <div class="tittle-text">
                                    <h3 class="mb-0 font-d-bld">' . $row["Headline"] . '</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="content-text">
                                    <ul class="mb-0 ps-0">
                                        <li>
                                            <p class="mb-0 font-d-bld text-white">' . $row["Content"] . '</p>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="play-btn">
                                    <a target="blank" href="' . $row["Link"] . '" class="text-uppercase text-white font-d-bld">' . $row["BtnText"] . '</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ';

            //increment the counter
            $counter++;        
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

---

**Suggestion**
you can also use CSS :nth-child() Selector to add margin and styling. That way your php code will be bit cleaner...

```
/* Selects the second element of div siblings */
div:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Read More about it here [CSS :nth-child() Selector - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.php)

Hope it helped..